# Matplotlib Same Histogram on two charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, subplot

I'm trying to create the same histogram on two charts in Matplotlib, and for some reason this code isn't working. I'm getting a histogram on one of the chats but not on the other.

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1 = diamonds['price'].hist(bins = 50, color = 'black')
ax2 = diamonds['price'].hist(bins = 50, color = 'black')
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not particularly clear from your code snippet what `diamonds` is but let's imagine it is a pandas `DataFrame`.

You need to pass the axis handle to each histogram plot.

```
diamonds['price'].hist(bins=50, color='black', ax=ax1)
diamonds['price'].hist(bins=50, color='black', ax=ax2)
```

[Here's](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html#pandas.DataFrame.hist) the docs page for the `pandas.DataFrame.hist` method.